# How to label each circle you draw when using the method create_oval() from module tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

How to label each circle you draw when using the method `create_oval()` from module tkinter in Python?

Comment: what do you mean by _label [each circle]_? like display a name next to it, or save a reference to the canvas object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it manually, by creating a separate canvas text object.

Here's an example that places the text in the center of the circle:

```
import tkinter as tk

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 200, 200

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT)
canvas.pack()

x0, y0, x1, y1 = 50, 50, 100, 100
canvas.create_oval(x0, y0, x1, y1, outline='black')

center_x, center_y = (x0+x1)/2, (y0+y1)/2
canvas.create_text(center_x, center_y, text='Label')

root.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image: screenshoot]

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in way to do this, but you can use the `canvas.coords` of the circle to position a label:

[image]

Here is how to do it for the top left and bottom right corners. With a little bit more manipulation of the coordinates, you could position the label at the other corners, inside the circle, above, or under it, or left & right.

```
import tkinter as tk

if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = tk.Tk()
    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=200, height=200, bg='cyan')
    canvas.pack()
    x0, y0, x1, y1 = 25, 25, 75, 75

    circle_A = canvas.create_oval(x0, y0, x1, y1)
    canvas.create_text(canvas.coords(circle_A)[:2], text='A')

    x0, y0, x1, y1 = 125, 125, 175, 175
    circle_B = canvas.create_oval(x0, y0, x1, y1)
    canvas.create_text(canvas.coords(circle_B)[2:], text='B')

    root.mainloop()
```